# Is there any way... (vb.net + SDF)

Tags: sdf

I have a SDF file (compact framework dbase) only for reading...

Is any way to embed as RESOURCE ??? and read it directly from EXE, without extract it!??????

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can right click on the database, select it as a resource, and have the DB deployed as a resource on every build.